# not awaiting thid party api call solutions

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-dynamodb

I'm inexperienced and recently bombed an interview that put me in a react app, using express routes. The app was a grocery item to do list. You type in an item (like 'milk'), a third party dummy api is called to return additional information such as quantity, and location in the store etc. The idea was this api is very slow and we don't want users to have to wait for the api to see their item appear on the front end.
The front end was a simple react component that had an array of items in a usestate hook.
The backend route first added to item to Dynamodb. Afterwards, the third party api was called and the additional details of the item were returned. Finally, the same dynamodb item was updated with the new data.
In the logic of the submit button handler, they wanted me to immediately add a new object to the react component's state array (so that it would 'appear' immediately). Afterwards, await the post route. Then, the entire list was fetched again and used to update the react component's state.
My confusion lies in:

1. Is it common to refetch the list like this (could also have been a contrived example for simplicities sake for the interview), I am not familiar with dynamodb and was thrown off by how they didn't have it set up to return the updated dynamodb object, and then have me use the returned object to update local state. If it is ok to refetch the list, do you do that from the react component or inside the express route and send it as part of the response?
2. Is there a reason to insert the item into dynamodb -> call the third party api -> update the item as opposed to calling the thid party api -> inserting the item with all information into dynamodb